# Change the date expression

Tags: r, date, datetime

I want to change the date expression. For example, I made an example like below.

```r
df <- data.frame(date = c("2012year05month1week", "2012year05month3week", "2012year05month4week"))
```

But, I want to make it changed as

```r
df <- data.frame(date = c("2012051", "2012053", "2012054"))
```

using R code. In my real data, I have so many number of dates. So, I want to know a simple way of eliminating `year` and `week` in column `date`.

Comment: Try `gsub('\\D', '', df$date)`